# Red raycast despite valid target in Unity VR

Tags: unity, raycasting, virtual-reality

I have a question regarding Unity VR and Interaction Toolkit.

When I point at a UI canvas element, the raycast turns from red to white (indicating that it is a valid target). However, when I create a plane or terrain, assign a custom layer to it and include the custom layer in the Raycast Mask, the raycast will remain red upon pointing on the plane/terrain (indicating an invalid target).

I don't know how to fix this problem. Any suggestions?

I created an empty plane which the user should be able to teleport on. I assigned the custom layer "test" to it. I have the XR Interaction Toolkit installed. For the right and lefthand controller I added the layer "test" to the Raycast mask (The Layer UI is included there as well, I have no issues with the UI canvas however). When I point at the plane I can teleport successfully, the raycast remains red however, which shouldnt be the case, since the layer "test" is in the Raycast mask.

**The issue remains, even when I deactivate my teleportation script!!!! So whenever I point at the plane with the custom layer, the line remains red.**

Teleportation:

```
if (rayInteractor.TryGetCurrent3DRaycastHit(out RaycastHit hit))
{
    if (((currentTeleportationLayer.value & (1 << hit.collider.gameObject.layer)) > 0 ||
         (middleTeleportationLayer.value & (1 << hit.collider.gameObject.layer)) > 0) /* &&
        allowedToMove*/)
    {
        PerformTeleportation(hit.point);
    }
}
rayInteractor.enabled = false;
```

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of this problem in a new, empty project? Once we can see exactly what you're doing, we'll hopefully be able to spot the error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will edit my original post above for more information.

Comment: I think I need to add a Tracked Device Graphic Raycaster component to the plane. I checked the UI canvas and the component is available there??? But I don't think this will solve the invalid color (red) issue.